# Is there a lifespan for a dvd rom drive?

Tags: dvd, burning, optical-drive, lifespan

Specifically a liteon dvd multi recorder. Which can burn and read dvd's.
Is there a specific number of burns which you can use? And after that, the burner will no longer work?
Do you know of any useful tips on how to have a longer dvd rom lifespan?If it has really a lifespan.

Comment: wondering the same thing myself... just noticed all of my most recent burns are bad, and i'm trying to figure out if it's a burner issue or something else.  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifespan only depends on the environment. If there is much dust/smoke/dirt/etc it may break sooner.

Also if the Drive isnt used regularly (reading CD or DVD is enough), it will break sooner.

Answer (score 0):

depends on the DVD too and the speed you wrote the DVD/CD. As fast as you write more problems you will have. I have different kinds of CD and DVD stored under the same condition. Sometimes I have problems reading a 4 year old disc and can read an older disc without problems.

With time, the CD/DVD start to deteriorate and lose information.

Kodak has a CD/DVD that they say will keep the data for 100 years.

Comment: i think the question is about the lifespan of the drive rather than that of optical media.